# Why can't I add a capture list to a closure property?

Tags: swift, swift2, closures

In my code, I'm calling some methods that take closures. And I pass the same exact closure every time. So I decided to extract the closure as a property. And pass that property every time I call the methods. This can greatly reduce duplicate code.

However, when I try to add the capture list `[weak self]` to the closure property, the compiler doesn't let me do it!

> `'weak' may only be applied to class and class-bound protocol types, not '<<error type>>'`

I don't know what that means.

MCVE:

```
class A {
    var num = 0

    let closure: (Int) -> Void = {
        [weak self] x in
        self?.num += x
    }

    init() {
        let b = B()
        b.doStuff {
        [weak self] x in
            self?.num += x
        }
    }


}

class B {
    var stuff: ((Int) -> Void)!

    func doStuff(stuff: (Int) -> Void) {
        self.stuff = stuff
    }
}
```

In the `init` of class `A`, I called `doStuff` with a closure. In that closure, the capture list works. But when I declare the closure as a property (lines 4 - 7), the capture list doesn't work.

Does this mean that closure properties don't hold a strong reference to `self` and has an implicit `[unowned self]` capture list? But that makes little sense to me...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Class/Struct properties usually get initalized *before* the `init()` method is called and therefore *before* the instance is properly allocated. The capture in your property is not valid because of this, `self` isn't initialized just yet.

You can make it work nonetheless by lazily initalizing the property:

```
lazy var closure: (Int) -> Void = {
    [weak self] x in
    self?.num += x
}
```

This works because lazy properties can only be accessed when `self` is fully initialised.

Currently it's not possible to have a constant lazy property, but this might change in the future. The only workaround I know of is to use a private setter:

```
private(set) lazy var closure: (Int) -> Void = {
    [weak self] x in
    self?.num += x
}
```

Comment: Hmm... That's nice. But then I don't have the `let` constant anymore. Is there a way to use `let`?

Comment: Okay. I'll go with that. But I'll accept other answers if they are better.